# Arduino DC and Transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, dc-motor

I'm learning Arduino and there's point that I don't understand

I know diode is needed to protect the transistor and arduino. I also know transistor is needed because arduino can't run dc motor by itself.

But I don't understand how it really works. I learned DC motor's red part should connect to 5V and yellow part should connect to ground. But in the picture Red line is connected to 5V but yellow line is connected to collector[image]. How does it really make DC motor to run? and why 5V is needed to DC motor and diode?

[image]

Comment: `red part should connect to 5V and black part should connect to ground` ... only if the motor is to turn in only one direction ... reverse wires to reverse the direction

Comment: That diagram is wrong.  The motor is directly connected to 5V and ground. The transistor will not be able to control the motor.   If you got this off the internet, don't trust that source anymore.  This is about as simple a hookup as there is, and it isn't even close to right.

Comment: If you're trying to use the Arduino's 5V and ground pins to power the motor, that's going to run into some difficulty too. It should have a separate power supply, ideally.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic by clicking on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: I've changed the picture so can you guys check it again? previous one was picture on the internet and this picture is from my professor's lecture

Comment: Draw the schematic.

Comment: Your "professor" would do better to provide a schematic.  A wiring diagram is something you give a field technician to follow to hook things up, or to a child.  Neither needs to understand the circuit.  To understand the circuit, you need a schematic diagram.  Schematics show how the circuit works rather than just how to wire it up.  Look at the schematic that Leoman12 provided and compare it to your wiring diagram.  Your wiring diagram is just boxes with lines.  The schematic shows how the transistor, the diode, and the motor work together.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to mention. Using a Fritzing diagram as a start to breadboarding electronics is ok but if you want to get more accurate and down to detail, a schematic is far better. There are a couple things wrong in this diagram: First, there is no mention of what NPN transistor is being used, hence why you are confused as to what wire is connected to which pin of transistor.  And by the way, different NPN transistors have different pinouts, if you compare 2N3904 to the P2N2222A, you’ll see what I mean. Another point, the flyback diode isn’t even connected in reverse parallel to motor. As final point, if someone makes a mistake on a diagram, it may be harder to spot on fritzing diagram when you are new yourself.

Shown below is a schematic of how a transistor can be connected to motor and used to control it. Notice what pins are connected to which points on motor and power rails. The transistor used here is bc548 as an example. Here the transistor will turn on for a dc input signal at base that will bias transistor in saturation mode (it will act like closed switch). When this happens, the dc motor will essentially be connected to 5V power and GND. Transistor is needed to control motor because arduino digital pins can’t source high current that motor may need and may not have enough voltage that a motor may require to turn on. Usefulness of transistor lies in the fact that to turn a BJT transistor on, it requires small current. This current comes from digital pin. But the output pins of transistor (collector and emitter) , can control much higher currents and voltages. For example if your motor needed 12V and 100mA, (certainly too high demand for arduino digital pin), but capable for a many NPN transistors.
The flywheel diode is needed to protect the transistor when the motor turns off. When you switch a motor off, it can produce a large  voltage spike that will damage the transistor.

For a general dc motor, there is no definitive polarity that is required. You may connect red wire to + power and black wire to GND. This will cause it spin one direction. If you connect red wire to GND and black wire to +power, then motor will spin in the other direction.

Now in your case, because you want to control motor with arduino through the transistor, the motor red wire will be connected to +power while the yellow wire is connected to collector terminal of transistor. Reason for this is because, when the transistor is off, it’s collector-emitter junction appears open circuit, thus the motor is off. Imagine open circuit at these pins and you’ll see how no current can flow. Now when transistor is on, the collector emitter junction appears as relatively low voltage (0.2 Vor 0.1V) which is almost like a closed switch. Thus the motor yellow wire has been essentially connected to GND, and thus a complete circuit is formed. To imagine this, simply visualize short circuit between collector emitter pins and thus it completes the circuit. Current can thus flow and motor can be on.

[image]

Image source: https://www.petervis.com/GCSE_Design_and_Technology_Electronic_Products/Transistor_as_a_Switch/Transistor_as_a_Switch_for_Motor.html

Comment: Depending on the specific motor, it may cause less wear on the motor to run in one direction than the other, so if you don't need it to run both ways I recommend following the +/- marked on the motor. The difference will only matter as the motor ages, though.

Answer (score 1):

In your top picture, with the motor's yelllow wire connected to the transistor's collector, the Arduino can start and stop the motor.

In the bottom picture, the motor is connected to +5V and Ground, so the motor will run all the time that power is applied to the circuit.  The Arduino and transistor cannot control the motor.

Comment: In the top picture, so the yellow wire is controlling the motor?  and why is 5 volt connected to motor's red line?

Comment: The motor will run if there is 5 volts (or so) between its terminals, so you connect the red wire to +5 V, and the transistor can connect the yellow wire to Ground when commanded by the output of the Arduino.

Comment: Can you elaborate just bit more? I can't understand sorry...